# How to install web browser on lxc (ubuntu 16.04) and display the page on the local host

Tags: google-chrome, lxc

I am quite new with linux containers.
I set a p2p network with the command:

```
sudo brctl addbr br-peer$IDX_PEER
sudo tunctl -t emu$IDX_PEER
sudo ifconfig emu$IDX_PEER 0.0.0.0 promisc up
sudo brctl addif br-peer$IDX_PEER emu$IDX_PEER
sudo ifconfig br-peer$IDX_PEER up
sudo lxc-create -t download -f peer$IDX_PEER.conf -n peer$IDX_PEER -- -d ubuntu -r xenial -a amd64
sudo lxc-start -n peer$IDX_PEER
```

How can I install google chrom on lxc ? and run it?
the other question.. where can the web page be displayed? on the lxc or the local host. I do not find this in the documentation. 
Can you please help me ? 
thanks